# Combining two databases together for seamless login

Tags: php, django, database, webhooks

I have 2 applications developed with two different frameworks. One is using pure PHP and the other using Python Django.

My question is related to database combination for seamless login. How does one even begin to have the following scenario?

1. User is created on python application with email and password.
2. User should be able to seamlessly login with credentials from one database to the other PHP application
3. If user wants to login directly onto PHP application, they can do that as well.

How would something like this be accomplished?

I tried a couple of options of combining webhooks, but do not have enough knowledge of this to even understand.

Comment: How about using redis streams as an event log for login that can be accessed by both python and php

Comment: I’ve done this several times; I built a custom Django backend that would divert to the non-Django system on a dedicated URL, setting cookies on both domains, with a token shared in a database column that both systems could access to avoid logging in twice.

Comment: Are these applications on the same domain/subdomain, or completely independent in that respect?

Comment: Let’s say you’ve got applications “A” and “B”. If someone is on A and goes to B, _must_ the be immediately logged in? So B needs to be able to “detect” that they were signed into A? Or is it when they go to B they can just login again and the backing database is used. Basically, do you want SSO, or shared database?

Comment: do these applications share a database?